# Confused about Instant, ZonedDateTime and UTC

Tags: java, utc, java-time, zoneddatetime, java.time.instant

im trying to understand the concept of UTC and the new TimeApi from Java 8.

```
Instant from = Instant.from(ZonedDateTime.of(2016, 12, 11, 00, 23, 24, 245, ZoneId.systemDefault()));
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2016-06-10 21:19:18");

System.out.println("Case1:");
System.out.println(date.toInstant());
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()));

System.out.println("Case2:");
System.out.println(from);
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(from, ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

The following output is printed:

```
Case1:
2016-06-10T19:19:18Z
2016-06-10T21:19:18+02:00[Europe/Berlin]

Case2:
2016-12-10T23:23:24.000000245Z
2016-12-11T00:23:24.000000245+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

Why the Zone Offset in `Case1` is  `+02:00`Hours, in `Case2` `+01:00`Hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2016-06-10T19:19:18Z` is in June (when Berlin is in Daylight Savings Time:  [Central European Summer Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cest)).

`2016-12-10T23:23:24.000000245Z` is in December (when Berlin is not in Daylight Savings Time: [Central European Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time)).

Hence the UTC offsets are different.